# Tikz Diagonal Line

Tags: pgfplots

How do I go about adding a diagonal line onto my chart. (red dotted)

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xlabel={False Positive Rate}, ylabel={True Positive    Rate},legend    pos={north east}, scaled ticks = false,tick label style={/pgf/number        format/fixed,/pgf/number format/precision=3},xmax=1,ymax=1,xmin=0,ymin=0]
\addplot[
scatter,only marks,scatter src=explicit symbolic,
scatter/classes={
a={mark=*,draw=bblue,fill=bblue},
b={mark=*,draw=rred,fill=rred}
}]
table[x=x,y=y,meta=label]{
x    y    label
0.316 0.888 a   
0.342 0.902 b    
};
\legend{AB,AA}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

[image: What I need]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're after the line y=x, just `\addplot [red] {x};`. If you're after the more generic lower left corner of axis to upper right corner of axis, use the `rel axis cs` coordinate system.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xlabel={False Positive Rate}, ylabel={True Positive    Rate},legend    pos={north east}, scaled ticks = false,tick label style={/pgf/number        format/fixed,/pgf/number format/precision=3},xmax=1,ymax=1,xmin=0,ymin=0]
\addplot[
scatter,only marks,scatter src=explicit symbolic,
scatter/classes={
a={mark=*,draw=blue,fill=blue},
b={mark=*,draw=red,fill=red}
}]
table[x=x,y=y,meta=label]{
x    y    label
0.316 0.888 a   
0.342 0.902 b    
};
\addplot [red,samples at={0,1}] {x};
\draw [blue,dashed] (rel axis cs:0,0) -- (rel axis cs:1,1);
\legend{AB,AA}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]